# In iOS, Firebase phone auth only sends SMS after reCAPTCHA verification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I have a weird case where firebase is not sending an SMS OTP code after the user successfully receives a silent notification. Its only working if I disable background refresh and force a reCAPTCHA flow.

The silent notification route used to work to all my users but it suddenly stopped with no errors in the logs.